# Can't we convert a void array to an int array?

Tags: java, arrays

I declared another array and copying the void array elements to that array and proceeding for a solution but it is showing that I cannot convert a void array to int array, why it is showing like that?

```
static void minimumBribes(int[] q) {
    int[] arr=new int[q.length];
    int dif;
    for(int i=0;i<q.length;i++){
        arr[i]= q[i];
    }
     arr=Arrays.sort(arr);
     sol: for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
           if(q[i]==arr[j]){
               dif=Math.abs(i-j);
               if(dif >2){
                   System.out.println("Too chaotic");
                   break sol;
               }
            break;
           }
     }
     }
}
```

Comment: this is the error I am getting, error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int[]
             arr=Arrays.sort(arr);
                            ^

Comment: What exactly is a *void array*? `Arrays#sort` doesn't return anything, which is why your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to int[]. Just write `Arrays.sort(arr);`  in your code

Comment: There's no such thing as a "void array"

Answer (score 1):

The java.util.Arrays.sort() method does not return any value. 
The problem is coming because of the line  `arr=Arrays.sort(arr);`

When you do Arrays.sort(arr); it over-writes the same arr array.
Please check the reference documentation. Function `Arrays.sort()` sorts the array in place and returns `void`. Replace

```
arr = Arrays.sort(arr);
```

by just

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

The function sorts the array you are passing in. If you want the original array to be unchanged create a copy using `Arrays.copyOf()` first.

Comment: @JBNizet, yes, you are right, thanks! I have edited my answer.